# Connecting GoogleApiClient before using FucedLocationProviderClient

Tags: android, google-api, location

Do I need to Connect GoogleApiClient first, before using FucedLocationProviderClient ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.. You dont need GoogleApiClient. FusedLocationProviderClient will work without GoogleApiClient.

Sample code to get location using FusedLocationProviderClient.

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

//Intialize
mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

//After get it the permission and GPS ON - write this below code
fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
            if (location != null) {
                //handle location
            }
        }
    });
```

Refer this - https://medium.com/@droidbyme/get-current-location-using-fusedlocationproviderclient-in-android-cb7ebf5ab88e